# Update XSD file when sql server schema changes in VS2010

Tags: sql-server, xsd, schema

I am having what seems to be a simple problem but I can't figure out how to get VS2010 to update my .xsd file when I change the schema in my sql server database.

I have found two recommendations thus far.

The first to right click the xsd file and 'Run Custom Tool'.  This does not update the XSD as far as I can tell since I my added table doesn't appear and a table with a new column isn't updated.

The second option is to delete the xsd file and then re-add the datasource.  This method obviously updates the tables but any queries that I added for the UI are lost.

Because this is a fairly large data model I expect that there will be changes (we are still early in the process) to the schema.  At this point it appears that my only recourse will be to move my UI specific queries into that database as functions are stored procedures...

Is there a best practice for this (or something I'm terribly missing with this toolset)?

Comment: +1 having the exact same dilema here

Comment: Have you tried deleted all the models from the xsd, not deleting the file. Then clicking ` 'Run Custom Tool` ?